# calculate difference between 2 dates from datetimepicker

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio-2010, date, date-arithmetic

I want to calculate the differences between two dates, one picked form dateTimePicker1 and the    other one 20 February of 2014 and store it in a string to added to my array and be able to display it in another form

THIS is my code:

```
    TimeSpan getDateDifference(DateTime date1, DateTime date2)
    {
        TimeSpan ts = date1 - date2;
        int differenceInDays = ts.Days;
        string differenceAsString = differenceInDays.ToString();
        return ts;

    }


    public class Patient
    {
        public string patientidString;
        public string firstNameString;
        public string lastNameString;
        public string dateString;
        public string differenceAsString;


        public Patient()
        {
            patientidString = "";
            firstNameString = "";
            lastNameString = "";
            dateString = "";
        }

    }


    //Array
    Patient[] patientInfo = new Patient[10];




    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSpan difference = getDateDifference(new DateTime(2014, 2, 20), dateTimePicker1.Value);
        if (textBox1.Text.Length == 0 || textBox2.Text.Length == 0 || textBox3.Text.Length == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(" Patient id, first name and last name cannot be empty");
        }

        else
        try
        {
            foreach (Patient patientinfoIndex in patientInfo)

            patientInfo[itemCountInteger].patientidString = textBox1.Text;
            patientInfo[itemCountInteger].firstNameString = textBox2.Text;
            patientInfo[itemCountInteger].lastNameString = textBox3.Text;
            patientInfo[itemCountInteger].dateString = dateTimePicker1.Text;

            string names = patientInfo[itemCountInteger].patientidString + "  " + patientInfo[itemCountInteger].firstNameString + " " + patientInfo[itemCountInteger].lastNameString;
            listBox1.Items.Add(names);
            itemCountInteger++;
            listBox1.SelectedItem = names;
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Contacts are limited to 20. Please delete some contacts prior to adding more.");
        }


    }


    //Search Button search a patients name and display his surname in the label if patient is found  display his surname
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int intTest = 0;

        for (int x = 0; x < patientInfo.Length; x++)
        {
            if (textBox4.Text == patientInfo[x].patientidString)
            {
                label6.Text = (patientInfo[x].firstNameString + "  " + patientInfo[x].lastNameString);
                PatientForm patientform = new PatientForm();
                patientform.Show();
                patientform.label6.Text = (patientInfo[x].patientidString);
                patientform.label7.Text = (patientInfo[x].firstNameString);
                patientform.label8.Text =(patientInfo[x].lastNameString);
                patientform.dateTimePicker1.Text = (patientInfo[x].dateString);
```

`patientform.label9.Text = (patientInfo[x].differenceAsString);`

```
                intTest = 1;
                break;
            }

        }

        if (intTest == 0)
        {
            label6.Text = ("not found");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You want the difference in number of days??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
DateTime febDate = new DateTime(2014, 2, 20);
DateTime pickerDate = myDateTimePicker.Value;

TimeSpan tspan = febDate - pickerDate;

int differenceInDays = tspan.Days;

string differenceAsString = differenceInDays.ToString();
```

If `differenceInDays < 0` then multiply it by -1.

**Note: In this case it's very easy to get the difference in hours, minutes or seconds as well.**

Here's an example of the above code in it's own method:

```
TimeSpan getDateDifference(DateTime date1, DateTime date2)
{
    TimeSpan ts = date1 - date2;

    return ts;
}
```

And when you want to trigger this method:

```
TimeSpan difference = getDateDifference(new DateTime(2014, 2, 20), dateTimePicker.Value);

//Now you can do what you want with the TimeSpan.

int differenceInDays = difference.Days;
int differenceInHours = difference.Hours; 

Console.WriteLine(differenceInDays.ToString());
```

Comment: where would is it best to declare it in a class, inside my form or a method also how do I state that my object dateTimePicker1 is equal to myDateTimePicker.Value

Comment: You're talking about declaring the TimeSpan object? You can put all the above code in a method if you want, call it something like `TimeSpan getDateDifference(DateTime date1, DateTime date2)`, and return a `TimeSpan`, or a `string` if you want, it depends what you want back from this method.

Comment: im talking about writing the code above and if i have to write something like DateTime pickerDate = myDateTimePicker.Value;

Comment: I would put it in a method for sure. I'll update my answer.

Comment: You don't really have to write `DateTime pickerDate = myDateTimePicker.Value;` You can use `myDateTimePicker.Value` directly I believe, some things are redundant for the sake of readability.

Comment: please check my question and see if you understand what im trying to do, the code works but it doesnt display any result

Comment: You should post another question I think. Ask how to take data from one form and display it on another. You've added fixes to your original question and now you are asking something completely different.

Comment: can you delete the code on the answer cause I need to use I for a project that will be check for plagiarism

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime a = new DateTime.Parse(string);
Console.WriteLine(datePicker.Value.Subtract(a).TotalMinutes);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract any two dates and it will work.

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2014,02,20);
DateTime date2 = dateTimePicker1.Value as DateTime;

TimeSpan difference = date1 - date2;  //dunno what difference you need so you can swap these
```

Comment: My bad, the difference should be TimeSpan, you are right.

Comment: Comment removed, sorry for being picky.